# How to executing range query on the field LocalTime type which have been converted to Integer type

Tags: java, hibernate-search

I created TimeConverter whichit extend AttributeConverter. The TimeConverter convert LocalTime to Integer and implements TwoWayFieldBridge.

in the database LocalTime = 12:23 has been saved as 1223. More example is below:

- 09:23 -> 923
- 00:42 -> 42

After all, I want to using Hibernate Search to gets documents for which integer meet the condition above open field and below close field from class RangeTime.

```java
@Converter
public class TimeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, Integer>, TwoWayFieldBridge {
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime localTime) {

        if (localTime == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return localTimeToInt(localTime);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Integer integer) {

        if (integer == null) {
            return null;
        }
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(integer.toString());

        for (int i = integer.toString().length(); i < 4; i++) {
            s.insert(0, '0');
        }
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
        stringBuilder.insert(2, ":");
        return LocalTime.parse(stringBuilder);
    }

    @Override
    public Object get(String name, Document document) {
        String value = document.get(name);
        return Integer.valueOf(value);
    }

    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
        return String.valueOf(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        if (value == null) {
            return;
        }
        LocalTime localTime = (LocalTime) value;
        luceneOptions.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, localTimeToInt(localTime), document);
    }

    private int localTimeToInt(LocalTime localTime) {
        return localTime.getHour() * 100 + localTime.getMinute();
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Table 
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Indexed
public class RangeTime {

...

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = TimeConverter.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
    @Field
    @FieldBridge(impl = TimeConverter.class)
    private LocalTime open;

    @Column
    @Convert(converter = TimeConverter.class)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "HH:mm")
    @Field
    @FieldBridge(impl = TimeConverter.class)
    private LocalTime close;

}
```

```java
//value is integer: 22, 2243, 1240
 open = qb.range().onField("place.monday.rangeTime.open)
                    .above(value)
                    .createQuery();

 close = qb.range().onField("place.monday.rangeTime.close)
                    .below(value)
                    .createQuery();

bool.must(open).must(close);
```

I haven't idea how to resolve this problem. I think problem is via wrong  BridgeField. Thanks.

Comment: After review I changed part of code`LocalTime localTime = (LocalTime) value;
        luceneOptions.addNumericDocValuesFieldToDocument(name, localTimeToInt(localTime), document);` to `LocalTime localTime = (LocalTime) value;
        IntField intField = new IntField(name, localTimeToInt(localTime), luceneOptions.getStore());
        intField.setBoost(1);
        document.add(intField);`

Comment: Now, TimeConverter to extend IntegerBridge, and implements AttributeConverter, FieldBridge